# No entity found for query Exception

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, ejb

I am executing the following lines:

```
  String queString = "some query string"
  Query q1 = em.createNativeQuery(queString, T03CallsLog.class);
  T03CallsLog newCall;
  newCall = (T03CallsLog) q1.getSingleResult(); //this line cause the exception after         the first time
```

weird situation.
if I only execute it with one instance it works fine, but if I do it parallel with more then one instance(mdb's) then the first one is executed without any exceptions, and all the rest get this error:

```
10:04:50,750 ERROR [log] ECMSDispatcherMdb.onMessage, error: No entity found for query
```

any idea what could cause it? and how it works the first time, but for all the rest of the instances it doesn't?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The error message usually tells you, that the query returned no result. And so `getSingleResult()` fails.

Consider using `getResultList()` and test the result with `isEmpty()` if you expect empty query results:

```
T03CallsLog newCall = null;
List results = q1.getResultList();
if (!results.isEmpty())
   newCall = (T03CallsLog) results.get(0);
else
   // is it a problem? -> log.
```

Answer (score 8):

If a query returns no result, a [NoResultException](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/NoResultException.html) is thrown by `getSingleResult()`. Are you sure, the seconds MDB, will get any results by your query?

Answer (score -1):

### Hibernate

The more specific entityManager in hibernate is the HibernateEntityManager. If you instead of

```
@PersistenceContext
public final EntityManager em = null;
```

Use the more specific

```
@PersistenceContext
public final HibernateEntityManager em = null;
```

Then you could use the

```
String queString = "some query string"
Iterator<T03CallsLog> q1 = em.createNativeQuery(queString, T03CallsLog.class).iterate();
T03CallsLog newCall = q1.hasNext() ? q1.next() : null;
```