# javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, exception, null

Before I posted this question, I already looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848776/no-entity-found-for-query-exception), but I couldn't get what I was looking for.

I know that for the query I wrote there may exist only one row or none at all. So, there is not reason for me to use `getResultList()`.

Here is my code:

```
String hql="from DrawUnusedBalance where unusedBalanceDate= :today";
Query query=em.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("today",new LocalDate());

DrawUnusedBalance drawUnusedBalance= 
    (DrawUnusedBalance)query.getSingleResult();// we can have only a
                                               // single datum per day
//`System.out.println(drawUnusedBalance.toString());`
```

The problem is, if there is no row, it throws an exception, and if not it works fine. I know the problem but I am also looking for the best solution.

What I wanted is, if there is no row in the DB I wanted to get a null object (instead of getting an exception) so I will insert a new data, if it is not null, I just want to update it.

There is one way to handle this, which I believe is not the right way to do it. It is: I will have a try-catch block and if it throws an exception I can write to insert new data in to the DB on the catch block. But I believe there will be a better way.

Comment: Try uniqueResultOptional(), which returns (you guessed it) an Optional<T>.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Yes. You need to use the `try/catch` block, but no need to catch the `Exception`. **As per the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) it will throw `NoResultException` if there is no result, and its up to you how you want to handle it.**

```
DrawUnusedBalance drawUnusedBalance = null;
try{
drawUnusedBalance = (DrawUnusedBalance)query.getSingleResult()
catch (NoResultException nre){
//Ignore this because as per your logic this is ok!
}

if(drawUnusedBalance == null){
 //Do your logic..
}
```

Comment: Thanks ManuPK ...But I still have to write some code which is creating an object and persist do a DB ..in the Catch block .... and I thought that will not be a good way to persist data from a catch block ... Though tnx for your response.

Comment: I feel there is nothing wrong in catching a **checked exception** and taking an alternative path. That why the JPA is giving you option on how you want to handle it. Actually the method you are looking for is available in [hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult()) which is not available with JPA.

Comment: @user1017111 I got your problem in writing code inside the **catch**. I have updated the answer slightly to make the code readable.

Comment: I should have mentioned to you I almost did it in that way after I got some clue from U. Again, thanks for helping. And I better rename my user name!!

Comment: Interestingly this solutions is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002993/jpa-getsingleresult-or-null

Comment: I am of the opinion that if your database isn't enforcing that there WILL be exactly one row returned from SingleResult then you should be using list().

Comment: the DB doesnt enforce that but the business logic does. You know what? In our framework, I found a method which will give me either the object or null ... thats what I was looking for .. Thank u guys again.

Comment: The link was helpful. How couldnt I find it from the very beginning?

Comment: I'm not sure. I found it when I was looking to prove that my approach is probably a better one.

Comment: @ManuPK : javax.persistence.NoResultException is not checked Exception. Its  unChecked Exception.

Comment: This is nonsense.  I have tons of existing code that does calls against the database, and if a single row is not returned then the object is simply null.  I am using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final and I've never seen this error until now.   There definitely is a better way that using list and checking for size or catching for an exception.   No thanks!

Answer (score 44):

When using java 8, you may take advantage of stream API and simplify code to

```
return (YourEntityClass) entityManager.createQuery()
....
.getResultList()
.stream().findFirst();
```

That will give you java.util.Optional

If you prefer null instead, all you need is

```
 ...
.getResultList()
.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: The question is related to `getSingleResult()`, not to `.getResultList()`. It's even stated in the description.

Comment: He's still taking a single element from `getResultList()` though.

Answer (score 7):

You mentioned getting the result list from the Query, since you don't know that there is a UniqueResult (hence the exception) you could use list and check the size?

```
if (query.list().size() == 1)
```

Since you're not doing a get() to get your unique object a query will be executed whether you call uniqueResult or list.

Comment: For now, I am using the query.list().isEmpty() to see if there is any data returned ... I thought it would be easy for the programmer if we were getting a null object like the get() method. Thanks

Comment: No problem. IsEmpty was obviously what I meant when I wrote my answer ;)

Comment: @Alex: The only problem with this approach is that you need to use an **additional query** to get the count. It might be a performance overhead.

Comment: Why would you need an additional query to get the count? You've already got a list containing all of the entities matching the query.

Comment: @Alex : Ok. Then **query.list()** should be stored separably and checked. I got your point and you are right.I got confused by the **if** condition.

Comment: Yes. If you want to access an element from the collection you would need to store it to prevent a second query from occurring.

Answer (score 4):

When you don't know whether there are any results, use `getResultList()`.

```
List<User> foundUsers = (List<User>) query.getResultList();
        if (foundUsers == null || foundUsers.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
User foundUser = foundUsers.get(0);
```

Comment: OK, it's a suggestion rather than an answer. But might be useful to others.

Comment: When you don't know whether there are any results, use getResultList().

`List<User> foundUsers = (List<User>) query.getResultList();
        if (foundUsers == null || foundUsers.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
User foundUser = foundUsers.get(0);`

Comment: This looks worse no?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use uniqueResultOptional() method, which gives you Optional in result:

```
String hql="from DrawUnusedBalance where unusedBalanceDate= :today";
Query query=em.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("today",new LocalDate());

Optional<DrawUnusedBalance> drawUnusedBalance=query.uniqueResultOptional();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String hql="from DrawUnusedBalance where unusedBalanceDate= :today";
DrawUnusedBalance drawUnusedBalance = em.unwrap(Session.class)
    .createQuery(hql, DrawUnusedBalance.class)
    .setParameter("today",new LocalDate())
    .uniqueResultOptional()
    .orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
```